# promisified GET call to rest api: can't get a valid signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, es6-promise

I am really having hard time understanding js behavior.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var crypto = require('crypto');



var options = {

  method : 'GET',
  uri : "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/order",

  qs: {
    signature : hash,

    timestamp : Date.now(),
    symbol : 'LTCBTC' 
  },
 headers: {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY' : 'PUBLICKEY'
  },
    json : true
};

var hash= crypto.createHmac('sha256', options.toString())
.update('SECRETKEY')
.digest('hex');

 //console.log(hash);
rp(options)

    .then(function (Bbody) {
        console.log(Bbody);
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

if i take the `hash` function and put it before the `options` one

it says (obviously)

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

but if i put it as in the code i shared, i get this error:

> StatusCodeError: 400 - {"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'signature' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}

and this is the output of the request:

```
 options:                                                                                                                 
{ method: 'GET',                                                                                                          
uri: 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/order',                                                                            
qs:                                                                                                                      
{ signature: undefined,                                                                                                   
timestamp: 1540392736646,                                                                                               
symbol: 'LTCBTC' },                                                                                                  
headers:                                                                                                                 
{ 'X-MBX-APIKEY': 
'PUBLICKEY' },                                
json: true,                                                                                                             
callback: [Function: RP$callback],                                                                                      
transform: undefined,                                                                                                   
simple: true,                                                                                                           
resolveWithFullResponse: false,                                                                                         
transform2xxOnly: false },
```

If i uncomment the `console.log()` i get the correct hash printed on video as first output, before the request rejection. Still the call can't catch it.

I have used as docs:

[binance api documentation](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

[this node documentation for the crypto library](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

[and this npm doc to promisify api calls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

P.S. : `PUBLICKEY` and `SECRETKEY` are placeholders but in my tests i used the correct strings.

Comment: you're missing a key, the function call is `crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key[, options])` you still need a key, options is the optional parameter and doing `options.toString()` will not return you a string value. You want to correct your code by simply adding an additional parameter for now `var hash= crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'secretkeytoken', options)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something called [variable hoisting](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-hoisting-variables) in JavaScript. Basically, JavaScript secretly moves the declaration of your `hash` variable to the beginning of the script as `var hash;`. When you're constructing the `options` variable, `hash` is still undefined.

Apart from the variable hoisting, I don't think you'll be able to generate a hash of a JavaScript object that should contain the same hash value in it. According to https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv1order, you need to take the following steps:

1. take all the *input parameters* for your request (symbol, side, ..., timestamp), and combine them into a query string, for example, `symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559`
2. compute HMAC SHA256 *signature* from the query string
3. make the request in one of the following two ways:

   - include all your *input parameters* and the *signature* as query parameters in the URL (for example: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&...&signature=<your sha256 here>`)
   - include all your *input parameters* and the *signature* in the body of the request, once again concatenated using `&`

Comment: According to https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv1order, you need to compute the hash from the query params like `symbol` or `timestamp` and *after that* you include another query param called `signature` where you provide the hash.

Comment: can you please edit your question to elaborate this comment? Bc when i've read it i understood it in this way: 
> Use your secretKey as the key and totalParams as the value for the HMAC operation
>totalParams is defined as the query string concatenated with the request body.

  totalParams for me is the whole options function.